# Datatable How To Change Show Entries

Tags: jquery, datatable

How to change Comobobox show entries 
[image]

with Textbox show entrie [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add aLengthMenu on your datatable properties.

```
"aLengthMenu": [[30, 60, 90], [30, 60, 90]]
```

This will display:

Show [30]   <-- Picklist
     [60]
     [90]

Best Regards